# Radical spacing/kerning on script-r symbol

Tags: amsmath, kerning

I have followed the directions on [this page](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/script-lowercase-r-in-latex.450030/) regarding how to make a script-r using the `calligra` font package.  I'm decently pleased with how the script-r looks, but the kerning with radicals leaves a little to be desired, in my opinion.

[image]

As you can see, the squared radical is positioned a bit far left of where I might expect it to be as compared to the regular "r."  I would think that shifting it right by a `\,` might do it, but being able to play with the spacing would be good.

How can I move the spacing of radicals for this `\sr` definition?  MWE below.

```
\documentclass[letterpage,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{6}{6}

%https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/script-lowercase-r-in-latex.450030/
% Declares the font 
\usepackage{calligra} 
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcalligra}{T1}{calligra}{m}{n} \DeclareFontShape{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}{<->s*[2.2]callig15}{}
% Makes '\sr' make a script r 
\newcommand{\sr}{\ensuremath{\mathcalligra{r}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \mathrm{R}^2 = r^2 + \sr^2 - 2r \sr \cos\omega
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reserving a math group for a single letter is a waste; you can do it more simply with the bonus that you can also add spacing around it.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

%\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{6}{6} % Are you sure? I wouldn't be. ;-)

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{calligra}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}{<->s*[2.2]callig15}{}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\sr}{%
  \mspace{-2mu}%
  \text{\usefont{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}r\/}%
  \mspace{2mu}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
R^2 = r^2 + \sr^2 - 2r \sr \cos\omega
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Grazie.  Appreciate the help.